# How to write select query in django in chain of one-to-many relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, one-to-many, database-relations

How to write select query in django? I have 2 one-to-may relationship

At the beginning, i am not very good at english. i am so sorry :). I have 3 tables. Driver, Car and Ride. The relationship between Driver and Car is (one-to-many: a Driver can have multiple Car. The relationship between Car and Ride is (one-to-many: a Car can have multiple Ride. I want list of drivers who have x times of rides.

My Models:

```
class Driver(models.Model):
    account = GenericRelation(Account, related_query_name='drivers')

class Car(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Driver, on_delete=None)

class Ride(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    request = models.OneToOneField(RideRequest, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
```

I expect something like this: `<QuerySet [<Driver: 1>, <Driver: 2>]>`which is Drivers with greater than or equal x Rides

Comment: Can you please share the related models? Actually by using Django you should not think about *tables* but about models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number of `Ride`s per `Driver`, and then filter on that number, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Driver.objects.annotate(
    nride=Count('car__ride')
).filter(nride__gte=x)
```

We thus first annotate each `Driver` object with the [**`Count(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#id8) of related `Ride`s, next we filter that queryset by specifying that the `nrides` field annotation should be greater than or equal to `x`, by using the [**`__gte`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gte). Here `x` is of course the number of required rides you need to fill in (for example `5`).